# Sharepoint MySite: Redirecting the Quick launch url

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I'm personalizing the MySite page with a custom controller and custom aspx, based in the original ones inside the SPSMSITEHOST folder. What I've done is copy them in my project, create a new controller .ascx and modify the copy of person.aspx and conten.aspx. Then I indicate in the the onet.xml the new path for my pages this way:

```
<NavBar Name="$Resources:spscore,SubNavTab_Overview_Text;" Url="person.aspx" />
<NavBar Name="$Resources:spscore,SubNavTab_Content_Text;" Url="personcontent.aspx" />
<NavBar Name="$Resources:spscore,SubNavTab_Tags_Text;" Url="_layouts/CustomMySite/thoughts.aspx" />
<NavBar Name="$Resources:spscore,SubNavTab_Colleagues_Text;" Url="_layouts/CustomMySite/MyContactLinks.aspx" />
<NavBar Name="$Resources:spscore,SubNavTab_Memberships_Text;" Url="_layouts/CustomMySite/MyMemberships.aspx" />
```

The thing is everything is working great. Every element in the quick launch menu is pointing to the right custom url and everything. Everything works great BUT the personcontent.aspx and I'm turning crazy here. The person.aspx is loaded in the same way and it works, why doesn't the personcontent.aspx? Should I change the url somewhere else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got with the problem. The url's are ok, but not the file type. It's necessary to mark them as Ghostable

```
<Modules>
 <Module Name="Default">
   <File Url="personcontent.aspx" Type="Ghostable"></File>
   <File Url="blog.xsl"></File>
   <File Url="tagprofile.aspx" Type="Ghostable">
     <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="LeftZone" WebPartOrder="1">
       ...
```

This made the trick for me.